# Make linear blur react on card

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, blur

I'm trying to do this:

[image]

But I can't find how I can make an linear blur for card in css or in React..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the element that you want, add an overlay.

```
.element:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, white 100%);
}
```

Comment: Its ok ! But can i add this at text ?

Comment: Add this to the div containing the text.

Answer (score 1):

use
`background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, white 100%);`
on the div in which you want this effect.